# what does that mean, C programm for RLE

Tags: c++

I am new to C so I do not understand what is happening in this line:

```
out[counter++] = recurring_count + '0';
```

What does `+'0'` mean?

Additionally, can you please help me by writing comments for most of the code? I don't understand it well, so I hope you can help me. Thank you.

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include<iostream>
    void encode(char mass[], char* out, int size)
    {
      int counter = 0;
      int recurring_count = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
      {
        if (mass[i] != mass[i + 1])
        {
          recurring_count++;
          out[counter++] = mass[i];
          out[counter++] = recurring_count + '0';
          recurring_count = 0;
        }
        else
        {
          recurring_count++;
        }
      }
    }

    int main()
    {
      char data[] = "yyyyyyttttt";
      int size = sizeof(data) / sizeof(data[0]);
      char * out = new char[size + 1]();

      encode(data, out, size);
      std::cout << out;
      delete[] out;
      std::cin.get();

      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: OMG, you want us to comment your code?  If you didn't write the code, seek out the original author.

Comment: Why is stdafx.h included twice?  Why are you event using it?  I suggest you turn off precompiled headers and search the web for "how to disable precompiled headers".

Answer (score 2):

It adds the character encoding value of `'0'` to the value in `recurring_count`. If we assume ASCII encoded characters, that means adding 48.

This is common practice for making a "readable" digit from a integer value in the range 0..9 - in other words, convert a single digit number to an actual digit representation in a character form. And as long as all digits are "in sequence" (only digits between 0 and 9), it works for any encoding, not just ASCII - so a computer using EBCDIC encoding would still have the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

`recurring_count + '0'` is a simple way of converting the `int recurring_count` value into an ascii character.

As you can see over on [wikipedia the ascii character code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters) of 0 is 48. Adding the value to that takes you to the corresponding character code for that value.

Answer (score 0):

You see, computers may not really know about letters, digits, symbols; like the letter `a`, or the digit `1`, or the symbol `?`. All they know is zeroes and ones. True or not. To exist or not.

Here's one bit: `1`

Here's another one: `0`

These two are only things that a bit can be, existence or absence.

Yet computers can know about, say, `5`. How? Well, `5` is `5` only in base 10; in base 4, it would be a `11`, and in base 2, it would be `101`. You don't have to know about the base 4, but let's examine the base 2 one, to make sure you know about that:

How would you represent `0` if you had only `0`s and `1`s? `0`, right? You probably would also represent the `1` as `1`. Then for `2`? Well, you'd write `2` if you could, but you can't... So you write `10` instead.

This is exactly analogous to what you do while advancing from `9` to `10` in base 10. You cannot write `10` inside a single digit, so you rather reset the last digit to zero, and increase the next digit by one. Same thing while advancing from `19` to `20`, you attempt to increase `9` by one, but you can't, because there is no single digit representation of `10` in base 10, so you rather reset that digit, and increase the next digit.

This is how you represent numbers with just `0`s and `1`s.

Now that you have numbers, how would you represent letters and symbols and character-digits, like the 4 and 3 inside the silly string `L4M3` for example? You could map them; map them so, for example, that the number `1` would from then on represent the character `A`, and then `2` would represent `B`.

Of course, it would be a little problematic; because when you do that the number `1` would represent both the number `1` and the character `A`. This is exactly the reason why if you write...

```
printf( "%d %c", 65, 65 );
```

You will have the output `"65 A"`, provided that the environment you're on is using ASCII encoding, because in ASCII `65` has been mapped to represent `A` when interpreted as a character. A full list can be found over [**there**](http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif).

### *In short*

`'A'` with single quotes around delivers the message that, "Hey, this `A` over here is to receive whatever the representative integer value of `A` is", and in most environments it will just be `65`. Same for `'0'`, which evaluates to `48` with ASCII encoding.